# .htaccess совмещение правила обработки

Tags: .htaccess

Дело вот в чем, при обращении к несуществующей странице вначале вызывается редирект с www на без www, после чего обрабатывается ошибка 404 (получается выполняются 2 правила по очереди редирект 301, затем 302 и ошибка 404).

Как переписать правило так, если страница не найдена сразу делать редирект на 404 с учетом с www на без www (то есть 301 и ошибка 404).

Для примера существует только 2 страницы index.html и 404.php (которая задает статус 404 not found)

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://site.ru/404.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site.ru 
RewriteRule (.*) http://site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://site.ru/404.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site.ru 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule (.*) http://site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Если обратились к www.site.ru **И** обратились к существующему файлу на сервере **ИЛИ** обратились к существующей папке **ТО** сделать редирект.

**P.S.** По тестируйте на файлах/папках, не уверен в приоритете выполнения условий.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает - это рабочее решение